# Connection closed without response in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, system-administration

I pushed a django website to heroku and getting this error:

```
Connection closed without response
```

here are the logs:

```
2015-09-08 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13    desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"    host=venta-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=3a95addd-ae30-4923-a13a-   ef9f92b1da16 fwd="81.95.238.91" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=159ms    status=503 bytes=0
2015-09-08 app[web.1]: [2015-09-08 09:29:59  +0000] [12] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
2015-09-08 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 187, in handle_request
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     six.reraise(exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2])
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_response(request)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 256, in handle_uncaught_exception
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     'request': request
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1191, in error
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1284, in _log
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self.handle(record)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1294, in handle
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self.callHandlers(record)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1334, in callHandlers
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     hdlr.handle(record)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 757, in handle
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self.emit(record)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 129, in emit
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 132, in send_mail
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 98, in mail_admins
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     new_conn_created = self.open()
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 796, in __init__
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 801, in _get_socket
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
2015-09-08app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
2015-09-08 app[web.1]:     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
2015-09-08app[web.1]: gaierror: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

from the logs it looks like it has something to do with `smptp`.

Anyone has experienced this problem before?

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you fixed this??

Comment: @Cheluis , it was a long time ago. Can't remember. Sorry.

Comment: Its a problem with Django logger, removed logging settings and it started to work